# Unexpected result with sortedArrayUsingComparator in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, sorteddictionary

I am trying to sort the keys of an `NSMutableDictionary` with their respective values (values in ascending order). My code snippet is as follows:

```
NSArray *sortedKeysWithValues = [[myDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
return [[myDict objectForKey:obj2] compare:[myDict objectForKey:obj1]];}];
```

The contents of the `NSMutableDictionary` are:

```
{
 806: "-89.06";
 802: "-75.12";
 837: "-77.76";
 803: "-84.75";
 808: "-115";
 804: "-102.12";
 813: "-115";
 805: "-115";
 801: "-67.53";
 836: "-70.36";
}
```

After the execution of the above code, the contents on `sortedKeyWithValues` becomes:

```
(
806,
803,
837,
802,
836,
801,
808,
813,
805,
804,
)
```

Notice that the key with the highest value lies at `5th` index of `sortedKeyWithValues`. And the key for `2nd` highest value is on the `4th` index and so on. It continues until the first index. The key with the value next to the first index lies at the last index of `sortedKeyWithValues` it goes up to the 6th index.

The order of the objects at `sortedKeyWithValues` that I'm expecting is:

```
(
801,
836,
802,
837,
803,
806,
804,
805,
813,
808,
)
```

What could be the cause for this strange outcome while using `sortedArrayUsingComparator`? Is it due to a bug with the method or some silly mistake from my side?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. You are comparing strings not numbers.

`NS(Mutable)Dictionary` has a dedicated method `keysSortedByValueUsingSelector` to sort keys by values and the selector  `localizedStandardCompare` sorts strings numerically. The `comparator` API is not needed.

```
NSArray *sortedKeysWithValues = [myDict keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

Alternatively use a comparator with option `NSNumericSearch`

```
id numericSort = ^(NSString * key1, NSString * key2) {
    return [key1 compare:key2 options: NSNumericSearch];
};

NSArray *sortedKeysWithValues = [dictionary keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:numericSort];
```

Comment: good idea, just keep in mind that `localizedStandardCompare:` order can change in future releases

Comment: @Aris I added an alternative

Answer (score 1):

only a couple of notes:

1) what is myDict inside comparison call back?

2) in callback you usually have to get values inside obj1 / obj2 AND compare data members inside them:
(eventually casting them... ) 
for example:

```
NSArray *sortedPeople = [self.persons sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){

Person *p1 = (Person *)obj1;
Person *p2 = (Person *)obj2;
    return [p1.surname compare:p2.surname];

}];
```

so I need to know why you use MyDict.

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because the values of the `NSDictionary` are `NSStrings`. `compare:` is doing an alphabetical sort.

Quick and dirty fix based on your code:

```
NSArray *sortedKeysWithValues = [[dic allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
    return [@([dic[obj2] doubleValue]) compare:@([dic[obj1] doubleValue])];}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
NSArray *myArray;

myArray = [myDict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

     if ([obj1 doubleValue] > [obj2 doubleValue]) {

          return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
     }
     if ([obj1 doubleValue] < [obj2 doubleValue]) {

          return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
     }

     return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```